# Is it possible to automate function overloading with Lombok?

Tags: java, lombok

I'm curious if it's possible to shorten function overloading with Lombok.  Basically I want to shorten this.

```java
public setUserDetails() {
    setUserDetails(null, null, null, null);
}

public setUserDetails(String firstName) {
    setUserDetails(firstName, null, null, null);
}

public setUserDetails(String firstName, String lastName) {
    setUserDetails(firstName, lastName, null, null);
}

public setUserDetails(String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
    setUserDetails(firstName, lastName, address, null);
}

public setUserDetails(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String phoneNumber) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

Into something like:

```
@CreateFunctionOverloads
public setUserDetails(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String phoneNumber) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: I removed the "or other tools" part of your question. Asking for recommendations for libraries/tools etc. is off-topic. It's fine if you limit the scope to lombok

Comment: Thanks, yeah it would be off topic of lombok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No but your API looks like it would be pretty error-prone to use, so perhaps that's a good thing.

The problem with 5 parameters that are all strings is that I can call it like this and it will compile completely fine

```
foo.setUserDetails("Smith", "Michael", "address", "phoneNum");
```

Do you see the problem?

> I switched the first and second arguments

This is the kind of thing that you will spend hours trying to debug only to feel like an idiot when you finally realise. I know because it's happened to me.

So I would abandon your idea. There are better ways to create objects with optional fields.

You can either use [`@With`](https://projectlombok.org/features/With) which creates new immutable copies of the object

```
new User().withFirstName("Michael").withLastName("Smith")
```

or you can use [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) which creates a single mutable builder instance and then a real instance of the object when you call `build`.

```
User.builder().firstName("Michael").lastName("Smith").build()
```

Comment: Oh yeah it's def error prone (not really an API just an example to showcase what I was wondering if possible).  I guess the same question could apply if I had different types as well.  I absolutely love @Builder and use it all the time.  For this use case the code already existed, I was curious if it would be possible to shorten without rewriting it as a builder.